# Sencha Cmd, Missing Required Arguments, Packages

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I've navigated to a workspace. I am running the Sencha Cmd commands as outlined in the two documents: [Creating Packages](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cmd_packages/cmd_creating_packages.html) and [Sencha Cmd Packages](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html). I have also run the `help` command for the below command. It is my belief the command is correct; however, I am getting an error:

> Missing required arguments
>   ...
>   name (The name of the package to generate)
>   ...

Here's the command - name included:

`sencha generate package --type code dog-bites`

What am I missing? Is the command complaining about the hyphenated name?

Comment: That should work. what version of CMD are you using.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I'm running OS X 10.10.3 and Sencha Cmd 5.1.2.52. The only way I was able to get it to work was to create the app from the Sencha sdk directory rather than supplying the path to the sdk in the build command.

Comment: @CD.. I am running v5.1.0.26

Comment: @MikeP I am relatively new to Sencha Cmd. Are you able to elaborate in answer form?

Comment: "This command must be executed in a valid app or workspace directory"

Comment: I'm curious. Have you found the cause?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, no worries.

The Sencha docs provide:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/touch generate app MyApp
```

to generate an app name MyApp. Instead of providing the /path/to/touch, try changing directories to the directory on your file system where you downloaded the sencha sdk, and run the generate app command directly from that folder instead. You'll need to provide the path to the directory you want to generate the app instead. Something like this...

From your command line,

```
cd /path/to/your/sencha/sdk
```

Then, to generate your app,

```
sencha generate app Myapp /path/to/directory/to/generate/app
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot, later, and see. Once I've got the time to roll around to it, I will take a shot (if it it works, I'll accept your answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to generate a package with that specific command then you must -

1. First create/generate a sencha workspace. Or be inside the same parent directory for an existing sencha application. `sencha generate workspace`
2. Once you've done the above you can easily run that command: `sencha generate package --type code dog-bites`

Suggested reading- [Intro to Sencha CMD](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/intro_to_cmd.html)

Comment: From OP, "I've navigated to a workspace". It is a valid Sencha Cmd workspace. I'll keep playing around, though, thank you for the answer.

Comment: I'm not able to recreate it at all. The only time I get that error is when I don't pass a name for the package.

Comment: Have you tried just running sencha generate package test ?